# All laravel routes are not found

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

i'm trying to deploy my laravel project to an nginx server, but all the routes are giving me a 404 not found page

i've pulled the project from my github repo then i change the directory owner to my user and run composer install, all things gone fine

this is my config file
/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_project

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/my_project/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

i've tries many solutions but no one works

Comment: Find the command for checking the nginx configuration file for your OS. This might give you a hint as to wether there is a problem or not. Did you restart nginx after creating your settings file?

Comment: yep i did every time, and no result :(

Comment: Does it serve static files? If you put an index.html in the webroot does it load?

Comment: yep it works, and also the first page of laravel works '/' but all other routes are note found

Comment: Have you tried using the recommended laravel nginx config? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#nginx

At a glance, i notice it uses `$query_string` instead of `$args` and the `fastcgi_pass` path is different, but that will depend on your version of linux.

Comment: yep i tried it also no result :(